# const initialization error with RequestInit in Typescript

Tags: typescript, constants, fetch

I am using fetch to call an API in typescript file like this but in browser it throws an error that const configInit must be initialized, which I think it is. Any idea how to solve this? thank you very much

```
    const authHeader = new Headers();
    authHeader.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

    const configInit : RequestInit = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: authHeader,
        cache: 'default'
    };

    const configRequest = new Request('/api/econfig', configInit);
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the `new Request(..)`  block try to call the **fetch** method directly, that will return a Promise

```
const authHeader = new Headers();
authHeader.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

const configInit : RequestInit = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: authHeader,
    cache: 'default'
};

const request: Promise<Response> = fetch('/api/econfig', configInit);
```